# How to stop counting point when player dies (Destroy)

Tags: unity, c#

In my game, I'd like to stop counting points when the player's y is -4. When the pink and red balls fall off the Plane the player gets points. But it seems a bit strange to be able to collect points after the player dies.

[image: The game is over, but the points are still pouring in.]

This is the code for the player:

```
     if (transform.position.y < -4)
    {
       Destroy(gameObject);
       gameManager.GameOver();
    }
```

And in the GameManager.cs I have this:

```
   public bool isGameActive;

   public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd)
   {
      score += scoreToAdd;
      scoreText.text = "POENG: " + score;
   }

   public void GameOver()
   {
      isGameActive = false;
      restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
      gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
   }
```

And this is the code for adding points when the enemies fall over the edge:

```
    if (transform.position.y < -4)
    {
       Destroy(gameObject);
       gameManager.UpdateScore(pointValue);
    }
```

How can I make the game stop counting points when the player dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the updatescore method you simply ask, whether isGameActive is true or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm when doing this, as suggested:
`if (isGameActive == true)
        {
            score += scoreToAdd;
            scoreText.text = "POENG: " + score;
        }`